# May I legally plug a EU device to a UK socket without an adapter?

Tags: legal, power

[image]

<sup>Taken from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fi5_CTBnDgc).</sup>

During short stays where the risk of a fire is negligible, am I permitted to plug my European devices without an adapter in the UK?

Comment: Devices sold in the UK must be provided with a fused plug, but you're not selling this. I doubt doing this is strictly *illegal*. It is, however, stupid.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking about the legality means this should be in [Law.se].

Comment: Since your question was about whether you're allowed to do this, rather than whether it's stupid (which, I repeat, it absolutely is), it's also worth considering that if you're staying in a hotel or other rented property this may well violate the conditions of that contract.

Comment: I am surprised this is physically possible! My impression was that the EU pins are very slightly closer together than the UK sockets would permit - I would definitely worry that you are stressing the plug and socket as well if you're forcing them together like this, adding to the risk

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about travel and the question is not worded in the right way to migrate it to an other Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @Andrew I can tell you this is very possible. You only need something to insert in the ground pin receptacle to enable the plug to enter the socket. There is then a slight resistance (mostly due to the fact that the EU plug pins are slightly angled towards one another), but it does fit. Whether it's a good idea (or legal) is of course an entirely different matter. But most people are probably quite bewildered by the UK wiring standards (and probably the other way around as well).

Comment: As authoritarian as the UK is, I don't believe the police inspect peoples' power sockets  regularly to find violations. You should be more concerned about safety.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried this with an EU plug and a UK socket and it does not fit. Therefore if you manage to get the plug in you have damaged the socket which unless it is yours may well breach some contract you have made with the place where you are staying.

As others mentioned in comments it is dangerous anyway.

Adapters cost a few pounds for one by a reputable manufacturer and less for an unsafe one.

Comment: It does actually fit quite perfectly. But you need to overcome the built-in protection of the socket by inserting something in the ground pin receptacle (the socket is made so that you can only insert all 3 pins or none at all), so it is clearly not designed to be used that way.

Comment: @jcaron either my plug or my socket is different from yours because it does not fit here. I cannot even get it far enough to hit the shutters.

Comment: Even if you manually open the shutters, the 16A plugs with rigid pins won't go in without excessive force and their larger size is very likely to damage the socket. The 2.5A europlugs with convegent flexible pins will go in with moderate force once the shutters are opened, but they can sometimes get stuck and damage the socket on the way back out. Either way I strongly advise against doing this.

Comment: As @PeterGreen says (but with links), the smaller [2.5A Type C](https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/c/) will fit a UK socket (the type C pins are ⌀4mm, the same as the thickness of the rectangular pins on UK plugs, which are wide enough  for the pair to line up). 16A type C and [types E and F](https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/e/) don't fit as the pins are ⌀4.8mm.  Sometimes it's possible to force them in, but they may get stuck and/or damage the socket, which is also the case with type E/F in a type C socket.

Comment: ... Electric shavers/toothbrushes in the UK use type C (our bathroom sockets have an isolating transformer and can supply very little current), so it's not completely unknown to see such a lash-up over here.  I've done it myself, but only with an extension lead that's essentially disposable, for short term use, and being careful about what I used to open the shutter.

Comment: @ChrisH The 2.5A Europlugs pins are 4mm diameter but are converging and springy and so will push against the sides of the holes as they are inserted into a BS1363 socket. The contacts in a typical BS1363 socket only grip the top and bottom of the pins, so the Europlug pins can spring back inwards and get caught on the back of the socket face.

Comment: @Peter, hence why I wouldn't plug it into a wall socket, let alone someone else's wall socket, but only into something that can be separately disconnected and was my problem if I broke it. I have suitable adaptors anyway, so this would be in extremis.

Comment: @ChrisH-UK The UK shaver plug is not type C but can be easily confused with it. They do not plug in to type E/F sockets. Type C plugs do however fit into UK shaver sockets.